# .htaccess file and uri routing in codeigniter not working

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter-3

My main url: http://localhost:8080/courses/Content/index/rd-sharma-solutions/class-12/chapter-3-binary-operations/exercise-3-1

I want my url to be : http://localhost:8080/courses/rd-sharma-solutions/class-12/chapter-3-binary-operations/exercise-3-1

Here is my **routes.php** file

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'Admin';
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = TRUE;
$route['index'] = 'Content/index';
```

Here is my **.htaccess** file which is in **project->application->.htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|assets|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [QSA,L]
```

[image: My Project Structure]

I want help in uri routing and want to shorten the url and also i want to remove the folder name.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: No It didn't helped me. I tried that way but still the same url.